# After sudo apt-get remove my login is looping

Tags: apt, wine, login, data-recovery

it is the first time i use this forum, i always tried to find answer by my own and worked out but no more know. So im still a ubuntu beginner.

I tried to install wine with *sudo apt-get install wine* and after two or three connection failure because of my poor internet the terminal asked me to use *sudo apt-get autoremove*. What I did. And after that the terminal closed and my screen went back to the login page. But when i tried to log-in the screen went black (there is a quick message but cant read it, to quick) and came back to the login page.

So i tried several things that i find on different topics, like reinstall the desktop (but not working as i had no more internet connection). I don't remember everthing as i had to go to the closest internet cafe to find any answers.

Pissed of that running arround i decide to create a live usb and tried to get my files back and install a clean ubuntu, but I can not access my files even with *sudo su* or *sudo -i* and then nautilus. That only shows me a empty home file. arrrrggghhhh

So now i'm here and ask you some help. I'm writting you from the live session and would be happy if you can help me fix my old ubuntu(14.04) or at least get my datas back, if possible, because i'm affraid they are gone.

I also tried the different solution from the similar topic but nothing helped, probably because there is no internet connection in my loop session, so maybe can i use the package from the live usb to fix my current ubuntu, if yes, how?

If you need more information, I will complete them if you ask.
I hope I was clear enough.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Goto tty1 by ctrl+alt+fn1
Try to reinstall  the lightdm package
    apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
    or
Install gdm by using command apt-get install gdm
It will solve the issue.